# Unable to access a function inside an Oracle package

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There is a package in Oracle - dbms_sqltune_util0 which I want to make use of.
When I run

```
       desc dbms_sqltune_util0;
```

i get the appropriate description.

But when I try to use the functions contained in this package it doesnt work. What does this mean? Should I get a license or something?
The query which I am trying to run is

```
      select dbms_sqltune_util0.sqltext_to_sqlid('select 1 from dual') from dual;
```

Comment: `execute` permission might not be there. check with `dba`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very good explanation of how it isn't working. Is it giving an error message? Is it just not doing anything? When I run your test code I get a proper return of the `SQLID`.

Comment: sorry about being vague. This is what i get..
 
                                                              select sys.dbms_sqltune_util0.sqltext_to_sqlid( 'select 1 from dual' ) from dual;
Error: 00904
DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 11 in 'select sys.<*>dbms_sqltune_util0.sqltext_to_sqlid( 'select 1 from dual' ) from dual')

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use an Oracle 12c package. Your tag says you are using an Oracle 11g database.
As far a I know there is no Express Edition of Oracle 12c yet so the answer is: Yes, you need a licence to use this package.

BTW: Even in Oracle 11g there is not every package available in every edition of the Oracle databases.

Comment: Oracle databases are licensing ignorant of themselves. They do not know whether you have a license to use a certain product or not. `dbms_sqltune_util0` is not a 12c package as it is available is 11g EE.

Comment: My Oracle 11.2.0.3 database does not know that package and the only documentation I found about it is for 12c.

Comment: Then you are in the same boat as OP.

Comment: @mmmmmpie I'm not sure it's 100% true that Oracle is ignorant of licensing.  The one exception I can think of may be the parameter [CONTROL_MANAGEMENT_PACK_ACCESS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10296.htm#REFRN10296).  I wonder if changing that can disable some PL/SQL packages.

Comment: @JonHeller without a non-EE version of 11g to test I cannot confirm/deny but what I can confirm is that in EE it is set to `DIAGNOSTIC+TUNING` which allows you to use those packages. I highly doubt setting it to `NONE` would invalidate those packages.